# Java Referencing Abstract Classes

Tags: java, class, abstract

I am trying to create a game in Java and within this game I am trying to implement a quest / mission system. I have come up with an idea to do this, but I am not sure how I would reference the quests or even if it would work at all. It works as such:

I have an abstract class which defines all of the variables and has a few simple methods. The file resembles this:

```
public abstract class Quest {
    public String name = null;
    public int id;

    public abstract int getPrerequisite() {
        return this.id-1;
    }
}
```

I then have a few files that set values for these variables like the example below.

```
public class MyFirstQuest {
    name = "A quest";
    id = 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if it is possible but is there any way that I could reference the files like so:

```
Quest MFQ = new MyFirstQuest();
System.out.println(MFQ.name);
```

or

```
Quest[] quests = new Quest[10];
quest[0] = new MyFirstQuest();
```

Comment: You are mixing up abstract classes and interfaces it seems.

Comment: Or something. Certainly not anything that resembles valid code.

Comment: Why does the abstract method have a body? Did this code compile?

Comment: if `MyFirstQuest` does not extends `Quest`, so, you a not allowed to do this `Quest MFQ = new MyFirstQuest();`. And then an abstract method cannot have a body, do you have compilation problems?

Comment: Abstract methods have NO method body, they are provided as a "template" for a class to extends and override that class/method. An Interface is similar, but all methods have code. An Abstract Class can have both abstract and non-abstract (regular) methods, basically making a "contract" that anyone who extends that class must adhere to. Hope that helps.

Comment: Start with the docs on [abstract classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
public class MyFirstQuest {
    name = "A quest";
    id = 0;
}
```

by

```
public class MyFirstQuest extends Quest{
    public MyFirstQuest(){
        name = "A quest";
        id = 0;
    }
}
```

and there are some tips :

- use `private` variables and use getters like this `public String
  getName(){return name;}`
- remove the `abstract` of the method getPrerequisite